# Разница между Node 8 и Node 12?

Tags: node.js

Критически ли они отличаются? Хочу изучить, но основной материал, который  нашёл, про Node 8.

Стоит ли тратить время на такой материал? Или есть смысл искать статьи именно по последней версии Node.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом версии ноды обратно совместимо. Если речь про какие-то базовые/стандартные вещи, то можно и по Node 8 читать статьи.

Самое ключевое в ноде произошло, когда начали поддерживать es6. Это было вроде как в 6 версии. Список поддерживаемых es6 фич по версиям ноды можно посмотреть [тут](https://node.green/).

Читайте статьи про то, чего нового в каждой версии, чтоб точнее понять. К примеру, я весной писал [статью про новшества в Node 12](https://suvitruf.ru/2019/04/30/5583/whats-new-in-node-12/).

Например, если вам нужно что-то параллельно делать, то можно использовать [Worker Threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), которые появились только в Node 10.

Так что, всё зависит от задачи.

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение. Как же проблематично программисту, не уметь читать/слушать англоязычный материал)))

Comment: @Nikita да, большая часть материалов всегда на английском. Так что рекомендую подтянуть, хотя бы до возможности читать документацию ^_^

Comment: @Nikita P.S. если вопрос помог вам, отметьте его как принятый. Галочка слева от ответа (: